# Date is changed after persist in database?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, jodatime

User inputs date from JSP page, and it converts to Joda `DateTime`, the string output is

> 2014-03-26T00:00:00.000+09:00

However when I persist this entity containing date filed in database, and retrieve and print out again, it becomes

> 2014-03-25T09:00:00.000+09:00.

I don't know why database make this change to minus one day.
I use postgres, hibernate JPA for application development.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the time zone is still `+09:00` in the database? It looks like it adjusted the time to a different time zone, in which it would be the same time, just represented with a different time zone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value in the database? Use pgAdmin app, the psql command line tool, or some other database admin tool to query Postgres directly.

What data type are you using in Postgres? You probably should be using TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. Avoid using the WITHOUT time zone type as it **ignores any time zone offset** info you may provide.

Despite the name, neither type stores any time zone info. The difference is whether you want Postgres to pay any attention to time zone info on incoming data. Be sure to read [the doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) thoroughly and play with it to experiment until understand how date-time works.

Read [Always Use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) by David E. Wheeler, a Postgres expert.

Comment: From psql command line tool, the date value is "2014-03-25", I use the date as data type, so as you said, it ignores time zone offset. Now I will try to read that doc, add time zone info to date column. Hopefully it could solve that problem.

Comment: @user2321728 Do you mean the `date` type? That has no time, so how could you have retrieved a date-time value as you quote in your question? Please be **precise** in your language if you expect us to help. Also, here's a helpful article by a Postgres expert, [Always Use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html) by David E. Wheeler.

Comment: For database, I use date type, while for mapping entity class, I use Joda DateTime type. The application only requires date info, time is not necessary, neither is timezone. Until I found wrong date is retrieved...Maybe a simple solution is to use String instead of Date type.

Comment: @user2321728 Or, instead of jumping around taking wild guesses at different classes and data types, you could read the documentation, search StackOverflow and the Google, take some time to study and learn. You would then find that Joda-Time offers a LocalDate class for date-only no-time and no-time-zone. You would find that Java offers the java.sql.Date field to match the SQL DATE type. And you would learn that it is rarely a good idea to ignore time and time zone if there is any chance of your software having to deal with entities or events outside your local town.